# Необычная функция main

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Недавно увидел в программе следующую версию `main` функции:

```
int main(int number, char** array)
```

Эта версия соответствует стандарту или это какое-то расширение компилятора?

Comment: Соответствует..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, соответствует.

Использовать `argc` и `argv` как имена параметров (`int main(int argc, char** argv)`) - это просто традиция.

> #### [[basic.start.main]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2)
>
> ... An implementation shall allow both
> (2.1)
> a function of () returning int and
> (2.2)
> **a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int**
> as the type of main ...

Comment: Я про типы спрашиваю. Насколько я знаю, в стандарте 2 варианта: без аргументов либо `int` и `char*[]`

Comment: @brut В стандарте-то как раз `int` и `char **`. Но открою секрет: В объявлении параметра нет абсолютно никакой разницы между `char *[]` и `char **`. Оба варианта означают `char **` и подходят для main.

Comment: а зачем тогда 2 разных типа, означающих одно и то же? или существут ситуации, где они разное означают?

Comment: @brut Они означают разное, когда их используют не как тип параметра функции. Почему для параметров так - тянет на отдельный вопрос...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, сейчас задам

Comment: Есть понятие "сигнатура" функции. В с++ она бывает двух видов. Один вид такой  `int _alias(int, char**)` другой вид такой `extern "C" def_function`. В первом случае - всёравно как называются параметры - линкер слинкует по сигнатуре типов (главное что б типы аргументов, и возврата совпадали). Второй случай - "старая" линковка. Тут линкеру всеравно какие параметры и какая функция. И если что-то не совпадёт - получим исключение. Для второго случая параетров может быть 0,1,2,10 или любое другое колличество. Как правило тут случай 1. Случай 2 можно сделать - написав свой обьектный файл "старта".

Comment: @nick_n_a Запись `extern "C" def_function` невалидная. С++ не разрешает опускать параметры функции или указывать их разными в разных местах (как это было в С). Да и в С это обычно является грубой ошибкой.

Comment: @VTT Я имел ввиду `extern "С" int funct();`

Comment: @nick_n_a Все равно, в С++ `extern "С" int funct();` будет объявлять функцию без аргументов. Так что если намеренно наврать про аргументы, то получим неопределенное поведение.