# Зачем нужны две эквивалентные записи char** и char*[]?

Tags: c++, c

Судя по [этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897649/313522), записи `char**` и `char*[]` в параметрах функции означают один и тот же тип. Зачем так сделано и в каких ситуациях они будут означать разные типы?

Comment: Просто такой синтаксис. Это одно и тоже. В любых ситуациях.

Comment: Я бы еще дополнил, что даже с указанием размера такая запись типа в параметрах функции всегда деградирует до указателя. Собственно причины существования такого поведения скрыты во мраке истории. Так что это просто один из кривых атавизмов языка наравне с прочими неявными преобразованиями.

Comment: Писал об этом [тут](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/03/30/pointers_demystified_p3.aspx).

Comment: @ixSci не могли бы вы оформить это в качестве ответа?

Comment: Это ссылка, её нельзя в качестве ответа оформлять. Может кто-то напишет подробный ответ, это будет лучше.

Comment: Собственно ответа на вопрос "Зачем так сделано" по ссылке не содержится. Ровно как и в [англоязычной версии вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454990/why-cant-we-pass-arrays-to-function-by-value)

Comment: @VTT, по ссылке содержится предположение. Точного ответа я не знаю.

Comment: Пожалуйста дайте вопросу нормальное "говорящее" название. Если вам не нравится мое предложение, то придумайте свое название.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК: В смысле "в любых ситуациях"? Это одно и то же именно *в параметрах функций*. За пределами параметров функций это - совершенно разные типы, не имеющие ничего общего.

Comment: @AnT да ладно? А мне так не кажется

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК: Это замечательно, но что вам "кажется" и что "не кажется" здесь нам малоинтересно.

Comment: @AnT я не услышал от вас доказательств. Лишь слова. Которые нам как вы заметили малоинтересны.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК: Молодой человек, о том, что такое "массив" в С и С++ написано тут уже много и детально. Перепечатывать вам детские статьи об азах С в комментариях, да еще и не по теме вопроса я не буду. Задайте полноценный вопрос здесь - вам все объяснят, хотя скорее всего ссылкой на дубликат.

Comment: @AnT почему вы решили что я молодой? :) Да нет, мне не интересно. Все-таки я ПЭХАПЭШНИК :) и на Сях не пишу (хотя чутка в них понимаю)

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК: Ну, как гласит известная пословица: "Первое, что вы узнаете о языке С, это то, что в С массив является указателем. Второе, что вы узнаете о языке С, это то, что в С массив НЕ является указателем." Ваше "чутка" по-видимому свидетельствует о том, что вы находитесь на первом этапе :)

Comment: укаазателью можно присвоить массив (рассмотреть массив как указатель), а массиву нельзя присвоить указатель (рассмотреть указатель как массив).  Указатель не массив, но может хранить адрес  начала массива точно также как и может хранить  адрес начала любой другой последовательности...

Comment: @AnT кажется я понял что вы имеете ввиду. Массивы на стеке? И все-таки от них тоже можно взять указатель, да и привести такую переменную к типу указателя тоже не проблема. [Пруф](https://glot.io/snippets/f62pkvlvpi)

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Не понимаю, о чем вы. Никто не спорит с тем, что массивы в С *приводятся* к указателям. Это, однако, не означает, что массивы и указатели "одно и то же". Наоборот, массивы и указатели - совершенно разные сущности, кроме возможности приведения не имеющие ничего общего.

Comment: @AnT ок, возможно я просто некорректно выразился

Comment: Квадратные скобки - ничто иное как синтаксический сахар. Запись *(x + 5) = 3 выглядит немного лучше в представлении x[5] = 3.

Answer (score 17):

Тип `char *[]` трансформируется (adjusted) в тип `char **` в списках параметров функций. Во всех остальных случаях `char *[]` и `char **` - совершенно разные типы. (`char *[]` - неполный тип. Не ясно, намеренно ли вы использовали в своем вопросе именно неполный тип.)

Ответ на вопрос о том, почему так сделано в параметрах функций, надо искать в истории языка С.

Короткий ответ на этот вопрос: это было сделано так для повышения обратной совместимости по исходному коду и семантике с языком-предшественником С - языком B.

Длинный ответ на этот вопрос: детальный ответ содержится в статье Дениса Ритчи ["The Development of the C Language"](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)

**1. Как и почему массивы в С перестали быть указателями.**

Подход к реализации массивов в языке С был изначально позаимствован из языков-прародителей - B и ВCPL (см. вторую часть раздела "Origins: the languages"). В этих языках "массивных" типов как таковых не было: объявление массива там всегда, во всех контекстах фактически объявляло обыкновенный *указатель*, вместе с которым сразу же автоматически выделялся отдельный блок памяти, на который этот указатель указывал. Доступ к элементам массива осуществлялся через обычную адресную арифметику указателей. Более того, такой указатель являлся самым обычным указателем - пользователь в любой момент мог присвоить ему новое значение и тем самым заставить указывать в любое другое место.

Изначально Ритчи планировал использовать такой подход к реализации массивов и в С. Однако (см. раздел "Embryonic C") этот подход быстро пришел в противоречие с идеей одного важного нововведения языка С: `struct` типов (которых не было ни в В, ни в BCPL). Если бы массив в С реализовывался как явный указатель, то структурные типы, содержащие массивы, сразу же превратились бы в нетривиальные многоуровневые типы. Они бы требовали нетривиальной "конструкции", "деструкции" и, самое главное, *нетривиального копирования*. И это при том, что в раннем С применение оператора присваивания к тяжелым типам не поддерживалось вообще (!), а "тяжелые" типы копировались именно и только через `memcpy`. Понятно, что копировать структуру, содержащую скрытые указатели через `memcpy` бесполезно. Здесь понадобилось бы некое неявное "глубокое" копирование, о котором в С тогда не могло быть и речи. То есть, в рамках B-шного указательного подхода к массивам, `struct` типы получались некопируемыми вообще.

Вот для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, Ритчи и отказался от идеи реализовывать массивы, как физические указатели. Массивы в С перестали быть указателями и превратились в *непосредственные* блоки памяти требуемого размера, т.е. в то, что мы имеем в С и С++ сегодня. При этом, во многом для того, чтобы сохранить совместимость с существующим кодом на B, массив в С стал на лету *неявно приводиться* к типу "указатель", через который и реализовывалась вся адресная арифметика для доступа к элементам массива. Так родилось всем нам известное неявное стандартное *array-to-pointer conversion*. Т.е. подход из языка B во многом сохранился практически неизменным на поверхности, но физический указатель исчез навсегда, заменившись на временный "воображаемый" указатель - результат неявного преобразования.

**2. Почему эти изменения не задели параметры функций.**

Однако в параметрах функций, как вы видите, был полностью сохранен подход из языка B - объявление массива автоматически преобразуется в объявление обыкновенного указателя. Т.е. в списках параметров функций (и только там) объявление `int a[]` практически эквивалентно объявлению `int *a`. Почему здесь все осталось по-старому?

Это объясняется в разделе "Critique". Буквально: "... это - живущее и поныне ископаемое, остаток B-шного подхода к объявлению указателей, в рамках которого массив, *только в этом исключительном случае*, интерпретируется как указатель. Этот вариант записи выжил частично ради обратной совместимости, частично в надежде на то, что он позволит программистам предупреждать читателя кода о том, что в данном месте ожидается указатель на элемент массива, а не указатель на отдельный объект. К несчастью, в итоге это скорее запутывает читателя, чем предупреждает его."

Это цитата - ответ на вопрос о том, зачем была сохранен синтаксис `[]` при объявлении параметров функций, несмотря на то, что он все равно эквивалентен указательному синтаксису. Т.е. это фактически прямой ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @AnT, отлично написано. Интересно мнение Ритчи, что `[]` синтаксис может кого-то запутывать, я никогда не задумывался.